# Open SAML and BC-FIPS

Tags: bouncycastle, opensaml

We are using Open SAML for for SAML/SSO flows . Open SAML has a reference to the Bouncy Castle BC-Prov . As part of the FIPS compliance we are registering the BC-FIPS provider , do we have to make any change in the Open SAML code to remove references of the BC-Prov and replace it with the BC-FIPS . It seems  Open SAML has a compile time reference to the BC-Prov and BC-FIPS and BC-Prov libs can't coexist as there can be run time issues.

Comment: Hi chandra, actually we faced the same issue recently. May I ask if you've found the answer to your question above?

Comment: Hi @HoangHUA did anyone found the solution ? How to solve this I am using opensaml 4.3